# Is the cardinality of the set of all isolated points in a second countable metric space at-most $\aleph_0$?

Tags: metric-spaces, cardinals

Is the cardinality of the set of all isolated points in a second countable metric space   at-most  $\aleph_0$ ?

Comment: Yes.${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: @DavidMitra: Please give a proof or a link

Comment: Write down what it means for a point to be isolated. Then write down what it means for a space to be second countable.

Comment: So, the question becomes: can a space with a countable basis have uncountably many pairwise disjoint open sets?

Answer (score 2):

"Second countable" means that your space has a countable base $\mathcal B$ for its topology.  If a point $x$ is isolated, then $\{x\}$ is open, hence a union of sets from $\mathcal B$, and hence an element of $\mathcal B$.

Answer (score 0):

A second-countable metric space $X$ is hereditarily Lindelof, that is, every subspace is Lindelof. I would prove a stronger result, namely if 
$Z\subseteq X$ has the property that every $z\in Z$ has a neighborhood $U_z$ such that $U_z\cap Z$ is countable, then $Z$ must be countable. Indeed, for each $z\in Z$ fix such a neighborhood $U_z$ and let $U=\cup\{U_z:z\in Z\}$. 
Then the family $\mathcal U=\{U_z:z\in Z\}$ is an open cover $U$ and hence must have a countable subcover, say $\{U_z:z\in Z_0\}$ for some countable $Z_0\subseteq Z$. Then $Z=\cup_{z\in Z_0} U_z\cap Z$, hence $Z$ is countable.

As a corollary, in a second-countable metric space $X$, if $Y$ is an uncountable subset, then we could throw out at most countably many points of $Y$, say these points form a set $Z$, so that every neighborhood of every $y\in Y\setminus Z$ intersects $Y\setminus Z$ in uncountably many points.